# setState hook not updating - though prevState shows correct value

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, webhooks

I'm using the state variable to keep track of my previous state.

The animation works (without index), but when I do

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
        animation.addListener((scroll) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                let position = Math.floor(scroll.value / cardWidth + 0.75);
                if (position >= restaurants.length - 1) position = restaurants.length - 1;
                if (position <= 0) position = 0;

                console.log("position: ", position, "index: ", index)

                if (index !== position) {
                    setIndex(prevState => {
                        console.log("previous: ", prevState, "position: ", position, "index: ", index)
                        return position
                    });
                    const { coordinate } = restaurants[position];
                    mapRef.current.animateCamera({
                        center: {
                            latitude: coordinate.latitude,
                            longitude: coordinate.longitude,
                        },
                         altitude: 2000, // zooms in when viewing specific location
                    }, {duration: 1000}) // not sure if duration is actually doing anything
                }
            }, 3000);
        });
        return function cleanUp(): void { animation.removeAllListeners(); }
    }, []);
```

The index never updates. I've tried checking the prevState inside the setState function and that updates, but if I print index outside of setIndex -- it doesn't update. How can I fix this?
**EDIT: Found the problem. The function never stops as it is always listening. How can I refactor my code to end the function so the state is changed?**

Output from console

```
position:  1 index:  0
previous:  1 position:  1 index:  0
position:  1 index:  0
previous:  1 position:  1 index:  0
position:  1 index:  0
previous:  1 position:  1 index:  0
position:  1 index:  0
previous:  2 position:  2 index:  0
position:  2 index:  0
previous:  2 position:  2 index:  0
position:  2 index:  0
previous:  3 position:  3 index:  0
position:  3 index:  0
previous:  3 position:  3 index:  0
position:  3 index:  0
```

**EDIT: Answer That I Found**

As many have stated below, useState is asynchronous and will wait for the function to end before updating. The listener is a function that keeps running once it's activated until the next render. Because of this, values only updated when it re-rendered. I decided to switch to useRef as it's synchronous and allowed me to keep the most up-to-date values without re-rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, for a couple of reasons:

- You create a closure inside `addListener` capturing the initial value of `index`, which is set to `0` via `useState(0)`.
- You supply an empty dependency list for `useEffect` meaning it will only ever run once when the component mounts

To fix it, you should supply `index` to the dependency list of `useEffect` to allow it to re-run thus picking up the newest `index`.

```js
useEffect(() => { ... }, [index]);
```

Alternatively, if you find unhooking / rehooking the event handlers is problematic, you can pass a function to `setIndex` that allows you access to the previous value e.g.

```js
setIndex(oldIndex => {
  let newIndex = oldIndex;
  if (oldIndex != position) {
    // update newIndex 
  }
  return newIndex;
});
```